# How to avoid duplication between mounting and updating a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In a Vue application I'm working on I have a number of form components that can be used to either create a new record or amend an existing one. While a form is open, it is also possible to click another record or click create, in which case the contents of the form are replaced or cleared respectively.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to avoid a lot of duplication between my `data` function and my `watch` functions.

Here's a simplified example of the kind of thing I mean:

```
props: ["record"],
data() {
    return {
        name: this.record ? this.record.name : "",
        age: this.record ? this.record.age : null
    };
},
watch: {
    record(record) {
        this.name = record ? record.name : "";
        this.age = record ? record.age : null;
    }
}
```

Everything I have to do to set up the form when it's mounted has to be done twice: once in the `data` function to set up the initial reactive properties, and then again in `watch` for any props that could change. This gets more and more difficult to manage and mistake-prone as the number of properties in the `record` gets bigger.

Is there any way to keep this setup logic in one place and avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
props: ["record"],
data() {
    return this.updateRecord(this.record, {});
},
watch: {
    record(record) {
        this.updateRecord(record, this);
    }
},
updateRecord(what, where) {
    where.name = what ? what.name : "";
    where.age = what ? what.age : null;
    return where;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the problem add a `immediate` property to your watcher which will make it call at initialization too. Therefore the initial value of your `record` property will be handled. Take a look at the code below:

```js
props: ["record"],
data() {
  return {
    name: "",
    age: null
  };
},
watch: {
  record: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) {
      this.name = this.record ? this.record.name : "";
      this.age = this.record ? this.record.age : null;
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [vm.$watch - Vue's Official API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)

Comment: Yours is a good method, but I've accepted another answer because it also avoided having to duplicate the declarations of all the data properties